# Duvida em exercicio de R

Tags: r

Estou com dificuldade em fazer o seguinte exercicio, alguem com conhecimento em R conseguiria ajudar nesse caso

Em uma competição de salto em distancia cada atleta tem direito a cinco saltos. 
O resultado do atleta sera determinado pela media dos cinco valores restantes. 
Voce deve fazer um programa que receba o nome e as cinco distancias alcançadas pelo atleta 
em seus saltos e depois informe o nome, os saltos e a media dos saltos. 
O programa deve ser encerrado quando não for informado o nome do atleta. 
A saída do programa deve ser conforme o exemplo abaixo:

```
Atleta: Rodrigo CurvÃªllo

1 Salto: 6.5
2 Salto: 6.1
3 Salto: 6.2
4 Salto: 5.4
5 Salto: 5.3
```

Resultado final:

```
Atleta: Rodrigo CurvÃªllo
Saltos: 6.5 - 6.1 - 6.2 - 5.4 - 5.3
MÃ©dia dos saltos: 5.9 m
```

Eu consegui até esse ponto

```
while(TRUE){


atletas[1,1] <- readline(prompt = "digite o nome do atleta: ")  

if(atletas == '') {
  break
}

if (atletas != '')
  for (i in 2:6)
  {  
  atletas[1,i] <- readline(prompt = "digite o salto: ") 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu escrevi o código com base no *snippet* que você escreveu na sua pergunta.

```
while(TRUE) {
  atleta <- readline(prompt = "digite o nome do atleta: ")
  if (atleta == '') {
    break
  }
  dframe <- matrix(nrow=5, ncol=2)
  for (i in seq(5)) {
    salto <- readline(prompt = "digite o salto: ")
    dframe[, 1] <- atleta
    dframe[i, 2] <- salto
      if (i == 5) {
        print(paste('Atleta: ', dframe[1,1]))
        print(paste(dframe[, 2], sep=' - '))
        print(paste('Media: ', mean(as.numeric(dframe[, 2]))))
        dframe <- matrix(nrow=5, ncol=2)
      }
  }
}
```